# How do web applications typically interact with Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization

I'm new to S3 and I'm wondering how real-world web applications typically interact with it, in particular how user access permissions are handled.

Say, for instance, that I have designed a basic project management web application which, amongst other features, permits users to upload project files into a shared space which other project members can access.

So User file upload/read access would be determined by project membership but also by project roles.

Using S3, would one simply create a Bucket for the entire application with a single S3 user with all permissions and leave the handling of the user permissions to the application ? Or am I missing something ? I haven't been able to find many examples of real-world S3 usage online, in particular where access permissions are concerned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical architecture is to keep the Amazon S3 buckets **totally private**.

When your application determines that a user is permitted to upload or download a file, it can generate a [**Presigned URL**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). This is a time-limited URL that allows an object to be uploaded or downloaded.

When uploading, it is also possible to [Create a POST Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) to **enforce some restrictions** on the upload, such as its length, type and where it is being stored. If the upload meets the requirements, the file will be accepted.

You should **maintain a database** that identifies all objects that have been uploaded and maps it to the 'owner', permission groups, shares, etc. All of this is application-specific. Later, when a user requests a particular object for download, your app can generate a pre-signed URL that lets the user download the object even those it is a private object.

Always have your application determine permissions for accessing an object. **Do not define application users as IAM Users.**

If there is a straight-forward permission model (eg all of one user's files are in one path/folder within an S3 bucket), you can generate temporary credentials using the **AWS Security Token Service** that grants List and Get permissions on the given path. This can be useful for mobile applications that could then directly call the Amazon S3 API to retrieve objects. However, it is not suitable for a web-based application.

Comment: Thanks, that sheds some light on this. So, say in the case of a hypothetical interface which shows a table of files each associated with a download link, the system would have to generate pre-signed urls for each file ? How would one handle the case where a user clicks on a download link after the pre-signed url has expired ?

Comment: Generating a pre-signed URL is a couple of lines of code, and doesn't need to call an AWS API. So, making the links is not onerous. You can specify the duration of validity. For example, make it available for 20 minutes, which is long enough to click on but not too long to cause trouble in case the link gets out "in the wild" (eg in a Tweet). If they click an expired link, S3 will give them an error. They'll need to refresh the app page that shows the links.

Comment: Slightly OT but regarding metadata, if one maintains a separate database for all domain-related information pertaining to uploaded files as previously discussed, what that is the role of S3 metadata? What would be some real-world usages of custom S3 metadata ?