# How would I display an image from s3 on a webpage in my flask app without saving it?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask

I have an ec2 instance running a flask website, and I want to get a certain image from s3 only if a certain user is logged into the site and display it on the homepage. The image can be downloaded with cli tools on the ec2 instance, but I don't want to save it to the harddrive. I want to keep the direct link to the object in s3 private.

Basically, can I do something [like what this user is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043036/how-to-read-image-file-from-s3-bucket-directly-into-memory), but instead pass the file into the template and display it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655279/how-do-web-applications-typically-interact-with-amazon-s3

Comment: What if I don't want users to be able to share presigned urls with each other?

Comment: Users don't share anything. If you want a user to access an image in S3, you generate a pre-signed URL in your app and display that link in your app so the user can see/download it.

Comment: Right, my concern is that a user can simply copy that presigned url from the page source or by right-clicking and choosing "copy image address" and email it to his buddy. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront [signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html#private-content-how-signed-cookies-work) can be used to serve private content.
It is possible to prevent misuse of cookies by:

- Encrypting the cookie
- Using a custom policy and including the IP address of the viewer.
- Specifying the shortest reasonable expiration time based on how long you want users to have access to your content.

Don't forget to create an [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) (OAI) to give necessary permissions to Cloudfront to access the bucket.